# How to get a UIMenuController to display with Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, uimenucontroller

I am trying to get a menu controller to display.
 I think I am meant to call `canBecomeAFirstResponder()` and override it but it is no longer a function, it is now a computed variable.

I have done the following:

```
class DrawView: UIView {

     func tap(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {

        let menu = UIMenuController.shared
        becomeFirstResponder() // This gives the warning "Result of call to becomeFirstResponder() not used"
        let deleteItem = UIMenuItem(title: "Delete", action: #selector(DrawView.deleteLine))
        menu.menuItems = [deleteItem]

        menu.setTargetRect(CGRect(x: point.x, y: point.y, width: 20, height: 20), in: self)
        menu.setMenuVisible(true, animated: true)

        setNeedsDisplay()
    }


    func deleteLine(sender: AnyObject) {

    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I tap it recognises the tap but the menu doesn't get displayed.

Comment: What issue are you having with the posted code?

Comment: Maybe, you are not adding a gesture recognizer to the view.

Comment: @rmaddy the menu doesn't display even though the tap is being recognised.

Comment: The code is working now as is. Not sure why it wasn't earlier. Anyway thanks.